# Custom (and multiple) components are better or worse than native ones?

Tags: forms, datetimepicker

We have the case of two components for date and timeslot (hour and minutes in quarters of :00/:15/:30/:45).

Here is how it looks like if someone uses a single component for each and uses the native components of what the framework supports

[image: data and time native components]

---

On the other hand there are mockups which are suggestions to increase usability.
This is the custom component for the hour selector:

[image: custom hour selector component]

and this is the mockup for the custom component for picking the date:

[image: custom date selector component]

Also will the date selector be more usable if the form contains both the native and custom suggestion?

*I could give you more context but there is some confidentiality. Go ahead and ask freely though*.

Comment: let me know what extra info you need that would make this question more useful. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My rule is to only use custom controls if the following is true...

1. Does the custom component make the task simpler?
2. Does the user find your custom component easier to understand?
3. Does it remove steps in the process?

But if the custom components are less familiar to users, do not work as well then it will add an extra layer of complexity to the task then you should avoid them. **They need to be very well designed, executed and meet the criteria above.**
Often browsers limitations can mean that the component can get very complicated to develop, so worth running it by a developer too.

Your example is date based, that is something that you will find has probably been done many times.

Check out how the following categoies of sites do it as their business lives/dies based on the simplicity of the booking forms:

1. Airlines
2. Train booking
3. Travel agents

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to Nielsen Norman Group

> **Non-Standard GUI Controls** - If you change the appearance or behavior of these units, it's like
>   suddenly injecting foreign words into a natural-language
>   communication.

source: [Top 10 Application-Design Mistakes](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/top-10-application-design-mistakes/)

So, **Custom components are worse than native ones**.

But this is not **BLACK** or **WHITE**, if there is a good need for a costume UI component of course it's better to use it instead of the native on.

You should read the article, it elaborates more on this issue and some more useful stuff :)

Comment: The reference to the Nielsman Normal Group. Good one!